# Task scheduler Windows 10

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

I guess this is easy but is eluding me, I have a working Powershell script that I wish to run as a Scheduled Task in Windows 10, however the script does not execute from the Task scheduler.

Script is hider.ps1

```
$fs = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
Get-ChildItem "D:\TV Shows\" -force | Where-Object {$_.psiscontainer} | ForEach-Object {
    if($fs.getfolder($_.fullname).size -lt 20mb) {$_.attributes = "directory,hidden"}
    else{$_.attributes = "directory"}
}
```

This hides empty folders in a directory

In Task scheduler I have put

Start a program    `Powershell`

Arguments      `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass –File "F:\Xaved Files\Hider ps 1"`

Comment: Do you see the terminated status in task scheduler? Was it 0x0 or an error?

Comment: I get Task scheduler successfully completed task with return code 1

Comment: So.. Microsoft identifies it with 1 or 0x1: Incorrect function called or unknown function called.
It's not a solution maybe, but please try this:
1-create a batch file that calls your script and verify that it works
2-schedule your batch indicating the starting folder as batch and script's directory.
Does it works?

Comment: @andreataroni86  Hi Andrea thanks - the script definitely works, if I run it in in Powershell directly it works fine, I have tried your suggestion but when the script is called it still is not running. It must be something to do with Windows 10 permissions but I am having no luck

Comment: have you configured the task with local admin profile and checked "use hightest privilege" in task configuration?

Comment: @andreataroni86 I have checked Run as administrator and I though -ExecutionPolicy Bypass meant any local  settings but I have still selected an Administrator profile to be the user, the task open Powershell but then does not seem to execute, nor however does it produce any error message so I am a bit confused

Comment: try to debug: in powershell insert pause commands so you should see what is executed and what not.

Comment: @AndreaTaroni86 I have attempted to insert a Pause command but for whatever reason the script is not running at all in Powershelll, I have resorted to running manually for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the "start in" directory???

Apparently, since windows server 2012, if a task doesn't have this field informed, the task doesn't run silently.

This worked in my case, and [also to this guy](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310230957/http://www.ihateolives.com/2014/04/04/scheduled-tasks-do-not-run-server-2012-r2/)